# Kong Enterprise on Postgres Master/Slave architecture

Tags: postgresql, master-slave, kong

I'm installing Kong Enterprise API Management (1.5) and am utilising the Postgress database option.  My setup is that I have 2 RedHat servers on premise.

- Both have the Docker environment installed.
- Both have Kong Enterprise, and initially, both instances of Kong talk to their respective, local container.

Nominating one node as the Master, (and the other as the Slave), I successfully setup postgres replication so that changes made to the master database tables are replicated to the slave postgres database (I've proven this works).

I now want to re-run the Kong container on my second node and this time, nominate for the KONG_PG_HOST environment variable (in my docker-compose file) to reference the 1st node.  The intention being that, irrespective of which Kong Node is processing the request, the live master database is only, on the nominated master.

Starting a shell script into the Kong container, I can ping the first node ok.

Still - if I specifically go to :8002/overview it seems that Kong has no route to any database content, as the landing pages of the admin portal says no workspaces exists and 'vitals are disabled'.
Pointing browser at 8002/overview works fine.

What else do I need to make sure exists, for a Kong container one node to to use the postgres database on node 2 ?  Postgres port 5432 is open on node 1 as I can connect remotely to is and postgres replication between both nodes works..

What have I missed ?

thanks -